# How to find number of failed grades and the number of general average?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, average

I have A table of students and their grades.

How can I count the number of failed grades (*<50*)
and find the general average ( I mean the average for every student ) using **sqlite**?

this is the table (studentTable):

```
sID LessonID grade
1     1      45
1     2      50
1     3      65
2     1      44
2     2      22
2     3      91
```

I expect the results like this:

```
sID  noOfFails   Average
1       1         53
2       2          5
```

Comment: If you know how to write an aggregation query, then you should include your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT 
   sID,
   SUM(CASE WHEN grade < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS noOfFails,
   AVG(grade) AS Average
FROM studentTable
GROUP BY sID
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fcd13/1

Comment: You can simplify the query a bit by reducing the sum part to

    sum(grade < 50)

Comment: @tomjen, true. I just think that this way might be more clear to show what is going on.

Comment: Yes, It work, you only  miss a "case" before "when". Now it's work perfect!!

Comment: @user2601018, sorry about that. I messed it up when turning keywords to uppercase :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `case` expression inside the `count` function:

```
SELECT sID, COUNT(CASE WHEN grade < 50 THEN 1 END) AS noOfFails, AVG(grade)
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run it as follows:

> SELECT sID, COUNT(IIF(grade<50,1,NULL)) as noOfFails, AVG(grade) as Average
>   FROM studentTable GROUP BY sID

[image]

Comment: Yes, But I think iif statement doesn't work in sqlite. instead, we using case. thanks